# multiple array of textbox and save it with one id number

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

so I have this in my code.

```
$name = array('john','jane','mark');
$age = array(24,23,26);
$bio = array('about john','about jane','about mark');
```

and this is my table structure

```
id | name | age | bio
```

Now, my problem is I really don't know how can I able to insert the data in one row with same id using php and mysqli. can anyone have an idea about this?thanks in advance.

example output:

```
id | name | age | bio
1 | john | 24 | about john
1 | jane | 23 | about jane
1 | mark | 26 | about mark
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not correct to have a multiple `id's` because in the future that's a real pain when finding a data.

Comment: @aldrin27 id is just my reference from other table..

Comment: Can i see your other table?

Comment: Can you include the two table's in your question?

Comment: @aldrin27 this is what i want to implement.. http://i.imgur.com/9WAxXAb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use an autoincrement column.  MySQL updates autoincrement columns on insert.

For example:

```
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

This is assuming you want a different id on each row.